# Graph a 3D plot given an equation with three variables

Tags: matlab, math, 3d

I have an equation:

`b*cos(alpha) - a*sin(alpha) + b*cos(betta)-a*sin(betta) - b*cos(gamma) + a*sin(gamma) = 0`

I want to create a 3D plot of this in Matlab with alpha vs betta vs gamma ( x - y - z ). I don't understand how to represent the equation so it could be plotted. How can I do this?

It is possible to assume that a = b = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what you have at hand. What does the equation show? Which form is it written? How does MATLAB plot different type of equations?

Fist, lets try to understand what type of function you have. It has 3 variables, but it equals to zero. A 3 variable equation generally defines a surface in 3D. In your case, this surface is described on its implicit form.

Now, if we look at the documentation of MATLAB, surfaces are generally plotted with `surf`, but `surf` needs 3 inputs (`x,y,z`) and you can not easily isolate your 3 variables.

Ah! but luckily, there is a thing called a search engine, that can gives us hints. Now that we know what kind of equation we have, we might as well use Google (or your favorite search engine) and type "implicit surface plot MATLAB", and that search will return a function called [`fimplicit3`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit3.html).

I think it seems to work:

[image]